# flutter firebase phone authentication isn't working after changing bundle identifier on iOS

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

firebase phone authentication was working fine with me then I had to change the bundle identifier for my iOS app, after this change it is not working any more.

I created new project in firebase with the new identifier indeed.
push notifications is already enabled
background modes is already enabled.
I created new app certificates for the new bundle id and uploaded it to my firebase project.
I am using the same APN authentication key that is used with the previous app.

on simulators, the authentication open the recaptcha and work through it.
on real device release mode, it doesn't work at all.

what is the problem here? should I create a new authentication key? I understand the key can be used for many apps.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as it may face others:

I had to info.plist files.

info-Debug
info-Release

I had to add the URL Scheme inside both files.

> CFBundleURLTypes            
> CFBundleTypeRole             Editor
> CFBundleURLSchemes           
> The reverse id in google services file